How do I express a chain of OR statements where the member constraint carries a continuous variable?
I am currently employed as a network engineer, focusing on network optimization. I've encountered a situation where a Boolean OR chain seems apt for modeling a job completion problem. The challenge involves expressing the following condition involving a continuous variable $x$:
$\frac{0}{T} \le \frac{{{a_1}}}{x} \le \frac{1}{T}\rm{OR }\frac{1}{T} \le \frac{{{a_2}}}{x} \le \frac{2}{T} \rm{OR }\frac{2}{T} \le \frac{{{a_3}}}{x} \le \frac{3}{T}\rm{OR }....\rm{OR}\frac{{n - 1}}{T} \le \frac{{{a_n}}}{x} \le \frac{n}{T}$
Here, $x$ is a continuous decision variable constrained by $0 \le x \le 1$. In our practical applications, to avoid division by zero, we replace $0$ with a small number $\epsilon$. The parameters $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n$ are stricly positive and they represent system configuration, and $T$ is a time interval.
Could anyone advise on the best approach to formulate this problem for optimization? Specifically, I am looking for insights on handling the continuous nature of $x$.
I would be more happy if a more general form could be derived. That is
${L_1} \le \frac{{{a_1}}}{x} \le {U_1}\,\,{\rm{OR }}{L_2} \le \frac{{{a_2}}}{x} \le {U_2}\,\,{\rm{OR }}\,\,{L_3} \le \frac{{{a_3}}}{x} \le {U_3}\,\,{\rm{OR }}.....{\rm{OR }}\,\,{L_n} \le \frac{{{a_n}}}{x} \le {U_n}$
But currently the previous form is ok.

You want to enforce
$$\bigvee_{i=1}^n \left(L_i \le \frac{a_i}{x} \le U_i \right)$$
Equivalently,
$$\bigvee_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{a_i}{U_i} \le x \le \frac{a_i}{L_i} \right)$$
Introduce binary decision variables $y_i$ and impose
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i &= 1 \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{U_i} y_i \le x &\le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{L_i} y_i \tag2\label2
\end{align}

A weaker alternative to \eqref{2} is to impose big-M constraints that enforce $$y_i=1 \implies \frac{a_i}{U_i} \le x \le \frac{a_i}{L_i}$$
as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac{a_i}{U_i} - x &\le \left(\frac{a_i}{U_i}-0\right)(1-y_i) &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \\
x - \frac{a_i}{L_i} &\le \left(1 - \frac{a_i}{L_i}\right)(1-y_i) &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$}
\end{align}
These simplify to
\begin{align}
x &\ge \frac{a_i}{U_i}y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag3\label3 \\
x &\le 1 - \left(1 - \frac{a_i}{L_i}\right)y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag4\label4
\end{align}
To see that \eqref{3} is weaker than the first part of \eqref{2}, just note that $\frac{a_i}{U_i}y_i \le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{U_i}y_i$.
Similarly, \eqref{4} is weaker than the second part of \eqref{2}.

Oh I see your formulation require less constraint !

You want to model
$$
\bigvee_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{k-1 }{T} \cdot x \le a_k \le  \frac{k}{T} \cdot x \right)
$$
Introduce a binary variable $y_k \in \{0,1\}$ for each $k=1,\cdots,n$, and impose
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=1}^ny_k&\ge 1 \tag{1}\\
\frac{k-1}{T} \cdot x +(a_k-\frac{k-1}{T})\cdot(1-y_k)&\le a_k \le  \frac{k }{T} \cdot x+a_k\cdot(1-y_k) \tag{2}
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $\bigvee_k y_k$ and constraint $(2)$ enforces $y_k=1\implies \frac{k-1}{T}x \le a_k \le  \frac{k}{T}x.$

For the general case, replace $(2)$ with
$$
L_k \cdot x +(a_k-L_k)\cdot(1-y_k)\le a_k \le  U_k \cdot x+a_k\cdot(1-y_k)
$$
Reorganising the terms yields
$$
\frac{a_k}{U_k}\cdot y_k \le x \le 1 - (1-\frac{a_k}{L_k})\cdot y_k
$$
which is equivalent to equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ of @RobPratt's answer, part 2.

This is correct, but (2) but can be replaced by a single stronger pair of inequalities.

@RobPratt could you please elaborate more, I do not know the line of thinking. Also this problem is very difficult because $x$ i a continuos variable

Thank you I have upvoted your quick answer
